# how can i get current page url id from ajax

Tags: php, ajax

i want to fetch id from url if my url is like this: mydomain.com/Login/update/29/2

$:

```
function itemSubmit(){ var id1 = "<?php echo $_GET['item_id']; ?>";
            alert(id1);$.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "<?php echo SITE_ROOT;?>Login/update_data"+id1, dataType: "json", }); }
```

Comment: Which one is the id? Where you want to fetch it?

Comment: i got error : 2:219 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: Are you getting your error on this line `var id1 = "<?php echo $_GET['item_id']; ?>";` ?

Comment: i want to fetch 29 & 2 from url

Comment: yes i got error for this var id1 = "<?php echo $_GET['item_id']; ?>";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var url = document.URL;
var stuff = url.split('/');
var id1 = stuff[stuff.length-2];
var id2 = stuff[stuff.length-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch 29 and 2 from your URL then you may do this.

```
var urlArray = window.location.pathname.split("/"),
    id1 = urlArray[urlArray.length - 2], //29
    id2 = urlArray[urlArray.length - 1]; //2
```

Comment: You mean you want to send `id1` and `id2` to your controller using ajax?